# Run proc file through plsql

Tags: php, plsql, proc

how to run pro C or PC file through oracle?

i have the set of PC files.I need to run it using oracle or any other language.It runs that

particular file automatically that is set of .PC files.I specified in it.and also i need

log or spool for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to precompile the Pro*C file - see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_10opt.htm#autoId0).  Once precompiled you will have a C file that can be compiled to create an executable that can be run.